# How to get the value of a column in the row with the first occurrence of another value in a particular column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table with the following columns:

```
|    Date    |    Pass/Fail    |
--------------------------------
| yyyy-mm-dd |      PASS       |   

| yyyy-mm-dd |      FAIL       |
```

How do I obtain the value in the "Date" column of the row with the first occurrence (ordered by date) of "PASS" in the "Pass/Fail" column?

Comment: Could there ever be two or more records tied with the same pass date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by` with `limit 1`

```
select * from tablename
where PassFailCol='Pass'
order by date
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to also capture more than one passing record should two or more records be tied as being first, then we can try using a subquery:

```
SELECT Date, PassFail
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    PassFail = 'Pass' AND
    Date = (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM yourTable WHERE PassFail = 'Pass');
```